# Running a script for wget some resources when openwrt start

Tags: openwrt

## !/bin/sh /etc/rc.common

START=95
STOP=10

start(){
        while true
        do
                exist=$(ping -c 2 www.baidu.com |wc -l)
                if [ $exist -ne 0 ];then
                        break
                fi
        done
        wget -O /zhuye.html  http://www.baidu.com
}

When openwrt restart,I want the system run the script,but wget doesn't work,Why?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it,just "changed wget -O /zhuye.html http://www.baidu.com" to "wget -O /zhuye.html http://www.baidu.com >/dev/null 2>&1"